# phpmyadmin - access denied on Ubuntu 20.04

Tags: phpmyadmin

Error during session start:

> Please check your PHP and/or webserver log file and configure your PHP
>   installation properly. Also ensure that cookies are enabled in your
>   browser.
>
> ```
> session_start(): open(SESSION_FILE, O_RDWR) failed: Permission denied (13)
> ```
>
> `session_start(): Failed to read session data: files (path:
>   /opt/lampp/temp/)`

[(Screenshot)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8jX6t.png)

Comment: Did you start the session with root permissions (i.e: using `sudo`)?

Comment: yes ofcourse, @DanielMassey